# incompatible pointer types passing 'char [3]' to parameter of type 'FILE *'

Tags: c, file, pointers

fread should return the number of times it reads "size". So I have assigned that value to a variable but when wanting to print the number I receive the error above.

```
FILE* card_raw  = fopen( memory , "r") ;
int buffer[512] ;
int readbytes = fread( buffer , 1 , 512 , card_raw ) ;
fprintf("%i" , readbytes );
```

Comment: Which line is the message referring to?

Comment: `fprintf`? Did you mean `printf`?

Comment: yes I meant printf

Comment: This should be made obvious by [RTFM](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf), specifically the function declaration `int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);`. You shouldn't need to ask these kind of questions on the internet. Read your programming book about the use of fprintf.

Comment: Please do not completely change the question when there are answers posted. If you have a new question, please ask it separately. I will rollback the edit, since it makes posted answers obsolete.

Comment: this is the main problem :) I thought there has to be a problem with the while loop that's why I wanted to print readbytes.You are completely right thanks for you time

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP completely changed the question from one regarding JPEGs to its current text.

Comment: I wanted to close the question and start a new one but as I am a newbie here stackoverflow didn't allow me to close this

Comment: @Pegi just ask a new question and leave this one alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int fprintf(FILE * restrict stream,const char * restrict format, ...);`

And you passed a 3 characters string `"%i"` and that's what it complained about.

In case of `printf` you don't need to specify the FILE stream.  The printf function sends the characters to the standard
output stream `stdout`.

```
printf("%zu",readbytes);
```

Also declare `readbytes` of type `size_t`.

<sup><sup>If you want to print it to `stdout` or `stderr` or some other file stream then the syntax would be `fprintf(stderr,"%zu",readbytes)` (Using `fprintf`)</sup></sup>

Comment: Either the `f` in `fprintf()` is just a typo or it's meant as a diagnostic message, so there's likely a `stderr` missing. **edit**: we [have a winner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511098/incompatible-pointer-types-passing-char-3-to-parameter-of-type-file/47511218?noredirect=1#comment81978150_47511098), it's just a typo.

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: That's actually the thing OP may have wanted because OP will check as you said how much is being read.

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: Yes, It seems so..we got a winner.